# Is the Java package name convention flawed?

Tags: java, naming

We're all familiar with the Java package name convention of turning the domain name around. I.e. `www.evilcorp.com` would, by convention, chose to have their java packages `com.evilcorp.stuff`.

Increasingly I'm getting fed up with this. As a commercial programmer, I encounter time and again that the software package name is completely irrelevant due to some rebrand, acquisition or similar.

In the opensource world there's less name changes so there it makes sense. However it seems to me the shelf life of many pieces of (commercial/internal) software are much longer than that of the organisation making them.

The problem is often made worse by software projects taking the marketing department's lead to use the name *du jour* they use refer to a certain project. A name that will, without fail, change 3 months down the line to make the emperor's new clothes feel fresh and new.

Because of this, I've mostly stopped using the reverse domain as package name. Granted, if this is done on a large scale, there's risk of name collisions, but surely this is mitigated by either using "unique" software names, avoiding generic words, or use the reverse domain for projects intended to be sold/released as libraries.

Other thoughts?

Comment: `We're all familiar with the Java package name convention of turning the domain name around.` - um..no we're not... :)

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: Pretty simple. Java (at the site Java.com) names their packages `com.java.etc.etc`. Apache (at the site Apache.org) names their packages `org.apache.etc.etc`. You see the pattern.

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: Cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: "In the opensource world there's less name changes" -- even there it's a problem, often I see projects that are now on say github but their package names reveal that they used to be at the reverse of net.sourceforge.xxx or com.googlecode.xxx

Comment: @nafg - right.  this is why I tend to register my own domain name for any open source project I start work on these days, because I don't necessarily want to tie its identity to some specific corporation (whether one like sourceforge or github that's providing it with a service, or one like my own company that provided the original motivation for developing it).  It needs to be free to be its own thing.

Comment: In my mind, it's not necessarily the issue that you have a domain implicit in the package name.  It's that it's not a variable.  So when it changes, you would need to change it in hundreds, if not thousands of places.  Thinking out loud, one solution would just have the compiler optionally understand something like `com.${domain}.package`, where the `domain` is supplied externally.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm going to quote the [advice Microsoft gives for namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx) (.NET's packages), which doesn't have the domain name convention. I think it's good advice for Java packages too, since I don't believe that a domain name represents a solid and stable identity.

> The general format for a namespace name is as follows:
>
> `<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]`
>
> For example, `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX`.
>
> Do prefix namespace names with a company name to prevent namespaces from different companies from having the same name and prefix.
>
> Do use a stable, version-independent product name at the second level of a namespace name.
>
> **Do not use organizational hierarchies as the basis for names in namespace hierarchies, because group names within corporations tend to be short-lived.**
>
> **The namespace name is a long-lived and unchanging identifier. As organizations evolve, changes should not make the namespace name obsolete.**

If even your company name is unstable, you might want to just start with the product name.

Comment: What do Microsoft recommend you do if another company has the same name as yours?

Comment: @Thorbjørn - litigation

Comment: @RevBingo, bad solution.  Who belongs e.g. "Prodata" to?  prodata.com, prodata.dk or prodata.se?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: A namespace, unlike a domain, isn't, and can't be owned by anyone. It is only a logical division or categorization of code. The chances of collision between you and that other company approaches zero, unless that other company also happens to develop software, in the same technology, and has a similar offering (in short - a competitor of yours). In that case, I'd take RebBingo's suggestion, unless you're okay with having a competing company that has the same name as your company.

Comment: As pointed out in @Thorbjørn's answer, the problem the Java naming convention solves for is not guaranteeing *constancy* but rather guaranteeing *uniqueness*. Note the Microsoft convention guarantees *neither*.

Comment: @user359996: Uniqueness is only required *within your own codebase* (i.e. classes you need to refer to by name, either your own or 3rd party), not universally. Striving for that is simply wasteful and overly verbose. Given that, I think these guidelines provide the required uniqueness, and also reasonable constancy. Why exactly do you think they don't?

Comment: @Allon Guralnek: I never said the .NET style doesn't *facilitate* **local** uniqueness and constancy. I said it don't *guarantee* **universal** uniqueness, in contrast to the Java style. I moreover said this is because the latter is not trying to *solve* for constancy (let alone verbosity), but rather *solely* for global uniqueness. I'm not saying the .NET style is bad; I'm just saying it's solving for a different problem.

Comment: @user359996: Like I said, I don't see why universal uniqueness is a problem that needs solving. Why would you need names to be unique across mutually exclusive code bases? And Java's style doesn't *guarantee* it, since domain names ownership can switch hands. A developer who owns jUtils.com can develop a com.jutils.* library that many use, and then sell his domain to a completely different developer who develops a different com.jutils.* library which is also popular, but has collisions with the existing library.

Comment: 1) I never said it's a problem that *needs* to be solved; I just said it's what they're trying to solve *for*. 2) The OP already answered your question as to who wants strong guarantees against namespace clashes: library developers. 3) Yes, obviously the convention only guarantees uniqueness for as long as you own the domain.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek if universal uniqueness is not a problem that needs solving, why does Microsoft suggest putting the company name in there? Surely that's just as redundant as organisational names. You might as well go with product name from the start.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Because it provides very good uniqueness, but not universal uniqueness, which is a big advantage. You still want to prevent possible conflicts, but aiming for universal uniqueness provides diminishing returns. It's better to aim slightly lower and reap additional advantages.

Comment: I think the strong uniqueness is more a Java problem. In .NET, the code of a library/executable is compiled to a single whole, called "assembly" (`.dll` or `.exe`). It contains all namespaces (packages) and compiled types inside in their binary form. The Java concept is different - the compiler produces a separate binary image of each class, and physically places those classes in folders replicating package hierarchy in the compiled output. Two libraries with naming collisions can override each others classes when referenced by a single project, which makes uniqueness a needed solution in Java

Comment: @Ivaylo: I think once the compiler output is packaged into JARs, which is the common delivery method in Java, the differences compared to .NET DLLs aren't as significant, and I believe the issue you mentioned no longer applies.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek, there is an exception I can think of -  *shaded jars* - an approach we use at our company. The shaded jar is a single executable which has the unpacked contents of all dependent jars. In theory, this should work as normal jars do, but I have seen how package name collisions break shaded jar application because classes get overwritten. The .NET alternative - puttig DLLs as embedded resources and loading them at runtime is safe from that problem. By strictly following RDN one could reduce such risks ,still uniqueness has to be maintained in the internal package structure as well.

Comment: My point is that a jar file is merely an archive of the compiled classes in their package structure. It can be manipulated with any tool capable of opening an archive with no problems (like the maven's shaded jar plugin), and is prone to human-made errors. The `.dll` / `.exe` is a solid file with more specific format. You can hardly achieve the probing and replacement scenario without involving "dedicated" tools, which unlike in the world of Java, is not among the accepted practices. The bottom line is that MS have good reason not to adopt RDN, while Java development scenarios may depend on it

Answer (score 16):

You are looking at the solution to a different problem, namely how do we avoid that programmer X and programmer Y step on each others toes by putting files in the same package.

The "just reverse your domain name" solve this in an elegant way, as you then are pretty certain that if X and Y are unrelated they will not pick the same package name space.

Comment: +1 "You are looking at the solution to a different problem."

Answer (score 10):

The convention is not flawed. People are flawed, as you have nicely illustrated yourself.

I can think of 2 benefits:

1. It avoids collision between independent developers. A domain is unique. Two people can name two different project the same, but a domain has exactly one owner.
2. It makes it easier to find the maintainer. If you inherit a code base, that uses some open source library, it better be in a package that helps you find it. By now it doesn't really matter, because you will most certainly be able to google it. But 10 years ago, this wasn't so evident.

Answer (score 7):

The reverse domain name was used to avoid name collisions in case different organizations use the same class names in their libraries. It is a simple solution and off cource has some drawbacks (e.g. what about name collisions for classes in the same organization?).

You are not obligated to use it, it is a convention not a do or die rule. For example, some Java programmers don't respect the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

But consider the alternatives. How would you, for example, like two fully qualified class names for a LogFactory:

```
a50e8400_e29b_41d4_a716_446655440000.LogFactory
f47ac10b_58cc_4372_a567_0e02b2c3d479.Logfactory
```

or

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
com.evilcorp.logging.LogFactory
```

So, in my thoughts, use whatever you like as long as it includes common sense and a consideration for the users of your library.

Answer (score 5):

When I start a new project, I always insist on an internal and unchangeable name that the marketing people may or may not know, as it will only be referred to in the source code. That way, I do not have to worry about project name changes and namespace pollution.

This scenario fits me, because the source code is not usually an important part of the product, i.e. projects are usually a closed-source, proprietary systems. However, in open-source projects where the source code is the product, this might not be feasible.